# How do I upgrade from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.4.6 in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu

Is there an easy way out to get the latest PHP? I have tried updating my package but none of it has 5.4.6 yet... if anyone knows on how to do it quickly, can it be shared here?

I've tried compiling from the source, but I am constantly getting:

```
 configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>.
```

In my `./configure` I've specified where `evp.h` is, `--with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl \..`, but still it gives me, that error `–`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

#### Installing PHP 5.4.* on Ubuntu 12.04

Simply add the PPA repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
```

And install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```

---

You may need to install add-apt-repository on Ubuntu 12.04. To do so, run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

#### Other New Versions

For PHP 5.5 (currently 5.5.30) add the PPA repository instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

For PHP 5.6 (currently 5.6.14) add the PPA repository instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
```

Comment: seems like this is not the latest 5.4.6?

Comment: PHP 5.4.4 for my install (there was one week)

Comment: wow....that worked!!!

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS: `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`

Comment: @Codemonkey and future people with same problem, you can run `apt-get install python-software-properties` to be able to use `add-apt-repository`

Comment: Is there anyway to specify the actual version you want say 5.4.10 or 5.4.19 or are you just stuck with the current old stable ?

Comment: @Moak or they just use the correct program name: `apt-add-repository` which is pre-installed in current Ubuntu ditributions

Comment: when i do this, i still can't find a newer php version with apt-get?

Comment: @Hubro, I fixed the `command not found` error using this solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/38035/279383

Comment: worked like a charm on linux mint `php -v 5.5.18` the key is adding the :ppa repos. On the ubuntu packages are still at 5.3

Comment: What about `5.6.6`

Comment: It says that Ubuntu 13.10 (and higher) won't be supported in the repository.  If you require PHP 5.4 use Ubuntu 12.04.x LTS.

Comment: WARNING: Unmet dependencies before try upgrade!

Answer (score 10):

Hai Look at the following page to update PHP 5.4 in Ubunthu

```
http://www.zimbio.com/Ubuntu+Linux/articles/D_AsJR2qAL6/How+Upgrade+PHP+5+4+Ubuntu
```

You can update by apt-get command in terminal. Open Terminal and login to su user . then try the following command to update

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
apt-get update
apt-get install php5
```

If you try in local user means, use sudo before all commands...

**WARNING:** - this will also auto-upgrade Apache (now 2.4) which has additional consequences, i.e. there are big config changes between Apache 2.2. and 2.4 that will prevent the Apache service from running afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

If the official Ubuntu repositories aren't updated (and I do not think they are yet, latest PHP version available should be 5.3.x), you'll have to download the source files and compile it yourself.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php

Comment: I actually tried that and got stuck with this error: configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>. In my configure I've specified where evp.h is is, --with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl  \.. but still it gives me that error

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never tried to manually build the php sources under linux. If it is not urgent, I'd recommend to wait for the official package to be updated, I do not think it'll take much longer. EDIT: try installing `openssl-devel` as suggested here: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=184406

Comment: @adit Always when you see something like "Cannot find `foo.x`", try ubuntus package search http://packages.ubuntu.com/