# updating php from 5.3 to 5.5

Tags: ubuntu, php, update

I'm thinking of updating my php from version 5.3 to version 5.5.

I was wondering if 5.5 is backwards compatible with 5.3 as it is 'just' a minor update (eg not 5.3 to 6.4).  Am I running into problems if I just update the php installation via https://serverfault.com/a/420288/124883 ?
Is there a way (just like nginx's 'configtest' option to test the dependencies? )

Or is it possible to have both versions running simultaneous as I don't have a test-server only a live server??

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.3 is not 100% backwards compatible with PHP 5.5. An important change is that the old fashioned mysql connector (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is deprecated.

More info on deprecated functions for PHP 5.4 => PHP 5.5: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

PHP 5.3 => PHP 5.4: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.deprecated.php

I highly suggest to do a grep on your source.

Comment: I'm only using postgresql via the PDO connector, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: In that case you only have to apply a grep for the rest. Luckily there are not that many deprecated functions left for you to search.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4 and 5.5 could display more warnings on different things. Depending on the PHP applications, those warnings / errors can be visible to the end user also.

Therefore I recommend you to upgrade the PHP in your test environment, and test if things work as they should, before you upgrade it in your production environment.