# how to update php from 5.3 to 5.4 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php5, ubuntu-14.04

We have a PC installed ubuntu 14.04, but only installed php 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4, not the last version. Now we want to upgrade to php 5.4.

I tried the solution by this post: [How do I upgrade from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.4.6 in Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/questions/420286/how-do-i-upgrade-from-php-5-3-to-php-5-4-6-in-ubuntu).

but failed, there is no error but reported to me: `php5 is already the newest version`. but actually, only php 5.3

Is there other way to upgrade php?

Comment: Php 5.4 seems already in apt-cache. But I can not install it.

Comment: I removed php 5.3 and followed the above post. It works fine for me